# d3: Appending multiple elements based on integer in data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to d3 and still working out some of the basics.

From what I understand you shouldn't need for loops with d3.

If I have the following data:

```
[
  {
    "title": "mine",
    "shapes" : {
      "circle" : 15,
      "square": 20
    }
  },
  {
    "title": "yours", 
    "shapes": {
      "circle": 2,
      "square": 18
    }
  }
]
```

how do I append 15 circles and 20 squares?

I know how to append an element for each item in an object, but not how to use an integer in object.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Also, here is a good discussion on the use of loops vs the enter, update, exit cycle: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44395461/7106086

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of the d3 data pipeline is to avoid *unnecessary* explicit looping and procedural code. Looping still has a place.

But let's say you want to be idiomatic, and not loop. Then when you need is `d3.range()`. It turns an integer bound into a list. E.g. `d3.range(4) == [0, 1, 2, 3]`. If you're going through a pipeline, have an integer, and need elements for every value up to that integer, the key snippet is:

```
g.selectAll('circle')
 .data(d => d3.range(d.shapes.circle))
 .enter()
 .append('circle')
```

which converts the number of circles coming in from your data item to that many circles. Unfortunately, it's not *quite* that simple in practice. You're processing a multi-level structure, and you probably want to not just produce N different circles, but vary those circles based on some higher-level context. So in practice it's more like:

```
g.selectAll('circle')
 .data((d, i) => d3.range(d.shapes.circle)
                   .map(j => [i, j]))
 .enter()
 .append('circle')
```

That is, for the i'th record in your data array, the data fed to create circles combines i with the values of j coming from `d3.range()`.

The full code's a bit longer than fits comfortably here, but [here's a live example on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mtoL74pMMkQIuIWIHECt?p=preview).

[image]

Colors are chosen by the order in the input data; shape positioning and opacity are chosen randomly.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much for your thorough answer and example on Plunker! I now have my circles generating correctly :) 

I've had a lot of difficulty with the data function by receiving the error " Cannot read property 'length' of undefined". My real data is actually nested much more than the example I used in my question.

I've found that writing:

.data(function(d, i){ d3.range(d.shapes.circle).map(j => [i, j]); }) 

causes an error where as in your example writing:

    (d, i) => d3.range(d.shapes.circle)

does not! I thought one was just short hand.

Comment: The problem with that substitution of regular functions for fat arrow functions is pure JS, not D3. You're missing a `return`. Fat-arrow functions are like `lambda`s in Python: no explicit return necessary. `(d,i) => 'whatever'` returns `'whatever'` implicitly. If you want a classic function, you need to return explicitly: `function(d,i) { return 'whatever' }`. Or in your case, `return d3.range(...`.