# d3 speed of adding svg elements one by one vs from bound data

Tags: d3.js, webassembly

I've got some data inside WASM C++ code that needs to be displayed. The display is static, so binding isn't super important. I'm curious about runtime of two ways of doing this (and any other factor folks think worthy of consideration). Two options are: for the C++ code to put the data in a JavaScript array (call it `theData`) and then call something like

```
svg.selectAll("bars")
  .data(theData)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", ...)
  .attr("y", ...)
  .attr("width", ...)
  .attr("height", ...)
```

**OR** should the WASM code call a JS function to generate each element:

```
function newRect(x, y, width, height) {
  svg.append("rect")
    .attr("x", x)
    .attr("y", y)
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
}
```

Comment: Speed issues apart, if you're using D3 without binding data you don't need D3 at all (just use plain JS), have a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44395461/5768908

Comment: Enter / exit pattern is very useful when you have a dynamic data to render and don't want to get lost with insertions / deletions / updates of your DOM elements... From the performance prospective, I don't think there is much difference

Comment: One thing I am using d3 for is putting axes on a chart. It's a bar graph, but plotted with rectangles.